# DropBox authenticate in cordova / phonegap (android)

Tags: oauth, cordova, dropbox, dropbox-api, phonegap-build

Im trying to add dropbox support in my phonegap app, but i can't authenticate. (via dropbox-js/https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js)

I use:

```
client.authDriver(new Dropbox.Drivers.Cordova({rememberUser:true}));
```

The app opens a login/confirmation-dialog/ok but locks in the last step

in browser works fine with:

```
client.authDriver(new Dropbox.Drivers.Redirect({rememberUser:true}));
```

Is there any solution compiling with adobe phonegap build?

Comment: Which versions of dropbox.js and Cordova are you using?

Comment: Cordova 2.7.0 / dropbox.js 0.9.2 / Test project: https://github.com/karacas/pgap_builder_test / Main.JS: https://github.com/karacas/pgap_builder_test/blob/master/js/main.js

Comment: @karacas Hey I made a new PhoneGap plugin for Android that uses the Dropbox Sync API.  [The source code is here on GitHub](https://github.com/rossmartin/phonegap-dropbox-sync).  [I made a blogpost on setup here](http://rossmartindev.blogspot.com/2013/08/phonegap-plugin-for-dropbox-sync-api.html)